bathtub faucet has steady slow leak
This is in reference to a stand alone bathtub, no shower. It has a faucet and two knobs for hot and cold water. I did some research and shut off the main water before disassembling the knobs to check the cartridges. They are Delta brand and came out easy enough. I thought maybe the nut wasn't tight enough because if I twisted the hot water knob a little harder than it's off position, the water would stop. The O ring on that knob looked a little thinner somehow than the cold water so I swapped them to see if the cart was the issue, but the problem persists. I'm not sure if it is the cartridge now since I didn't have a problem with the cold one and swapping them didn't help. What else should I look for? I am avoiding buying a whole new cart unless it is very likely to be the issue as I see them at home Depot for $80.
Thank you!

If you purchased the faucet the parts should be "free" (covered by warranty.) However, if you purchased a house that had the faucet already installed, you do need to buy them. Are you sure you're looking at the right cartridge? Single-handle delta tub cartidges seem to be that high, the two they show as "older two handle" are more like $25-30 for the brass stem side-screw (RP24096) and under $15 for the plastic stem top-screw (RP1740) https://www.deltafaucet.com/service-parts/find-parts-and-identify-product/common-parts/tub-shower/leaks/two-handle-cartridges

Could you please specify what exact faucet or cartrdge model you have, and/or [edit] to include pictures?
